# MySQL select products with properties and properties values - grouped

Tags: mysql, select, e-commerce

I'm developing custom ecommerce solution. I came to point that I'm not able to get products with their properties & properties values - grouped by name.
For example user is in category_01 where are 5 products. I want to show him properties filter with available values. But only properties & values of this 5 products. I'm able to get grouped properties titles but I have no idea how to get also grouped properties values.

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_products` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`price` double(10,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `shop_products_properties` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `product_id_foreign` (`product_id`),
CONSTRAINT `product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) 
REFERENCES `shop_products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE `shop_products_properties_values` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`property_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `values_property_id_foreign` (`property_id`),
CONSTRAINT `values_property_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) 
REFERENCES `shop_products_properties` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I'm using Laravel so I get filtered products with hasMany properties with hasMany values. This works fine but now I need to group properties by title and group their values by value.

Example:

```
1.Product
shop_products: T-shirt
shop_products_properties: Color, Size, Material
shop_products_properties_values: Black, Red, White, XS, S, M, Cotton

2.Product
shop_products: Hoodie
shop_products_properties: Color, Size
shop_products_properties_values: Red, Green, White, M, L, XL
```

And I need to get result like:

```
Colors: Black, Red, White, Green, White
Sizes: XS, S, M, L, XL
Materials: Cotton
```

I don't know if it's possible to create mysql query to get this result or I should filter and customize collection... I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've interpreted your data structures correctly, this query will do what you want.

```
SELECT p.title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT v.value ORDER BY v.value) AS `values`
FROM shop_products_properties p
LEFT JOIN shop_products_properties_values v
ON v.property_id=p.id
GROUP BY p.title
```

Output:

```
title       values
Color       Black,Green,Red,White
Material    Cotton
Size        L,M,S,XL,XS
```

[Demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/ZLOG91342)